# Regular expression to match all digits of unknown length except the last 4 digits

Tags: regex

There is a number with unknown length and the idea is to build a regular expression which matches all digits except last 4 digits.

I have tried a lot to achieve this but no luck yet.

Currently I have this regex: "^(\d*)\d{0}\d{0}\d{0}\d{0}.*$"

Input: 123456789089775

Expected output: XXXXXXXXXXX9775

which I am using as follows(and this doesn't work):

```
String accountNumber ="123456789089775";
String pattern = "^(\\d*)\\d{1}\\d{1}\\d{1}\\d{1}.*$";
String result = accountNumber.replaceAll(pattern, "X");
```

Please suggest how I should approach this problem or give me the solution. 
In this case my whole point is to negate the regex : "\d{4}$"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
\G\d(?=\d{4,}$)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/HZAeJr/1).

**Details**

- `\G` - start of string or end of the previous match
- `\d` - a digit
- `(?=\d{4,}$)` - a positive lookahead that requires 4 or more digits up to the end of the string immediately to the right of the current location.

[Java demo](https://ideone.com/0oT7JV):

```
String accountNumber ="123456789089775";
String pattern = "\\G\\d(?=\\d{4,}$)"; // Or \\G.(?=.{4,}$)
String result = accountNumber.replaceAll(pattern, "X");
System.out.println(result); // => XXXXXXXXXXX9775
```

Answer (score 3):

still not allowed to comment as I don't have that "50 rep" yet but DDeMartini's answer would swallow prefixed non-number-accounts as "^(.*)" would match stuff like abcdef1234 as well - stick to your \d-syntax

```
"^(\\d+)(\\d{4}$)"
```

seems to work fine and demands numbers (minimum length 6 chars). Tested it like

```
public class AccountNumberPadder {

    private static final Pattern LAST_FOUR_DIGITS = Pattern.compile("^(\\d+)(\\d{4})");

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] accountNumbers = new String[] { "123456789089775", "999775", "1234567890897" };
        for (String accountNumber : accountNumbers) {
            Matcher m = LAST_FOUR_DIGITS.matcher(accountNumber);
            if (m.find()) {
                System.out.println(paddIt(accountNumber, m));
            } else {
                throw new RuntimeException(String.format("Whooaaa - don't work for %s", accountNumber));
            }
        }
    }

    public static String paddIt(String input, Matcher m) {
        StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < m.group(1).length(); i++) {
            b.append("X");
        }
       return input.replace(m.group(1), b.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, it would swallow more than numbers.  Could refactor it slightly as:  "^([0-9]+)[0-9]{4}"

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
String pattern = "^(.*)[0-9]{4}$";
```

Addendum after comment:  A refactor to only match full numerics could look like this:

```
String pattern = "^([0-9]+)[0-9]{4}$";
```

Comment: I believe you are right. I will test this out and accept the answer once it works. I had built a regex like this but I believe I wasn't clear about keeping part of regex within parentheses because to me it looked like a match for whole number but I guess the parentheses regex only gets matched with the string/number.